# Not getting Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to create reports using *iReport* for two pages bills and allotment. I've created report for bill page from *Java*application and it works fine. But the report done for allotment is not working and every time it says the document has no pages from *Java* application but it shows result on previewing.

I'm using this code:

```
    String str = jTextField5.getText();
    try {
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con;
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:kbg");
       JasperDesign jasperDesign=JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\showroom\\Report.jrxml");
       String sql="select * from bill where billid = '"+str+"'";
       JRDesignQuery newQuery=new JRDesignQuery();
       newQuery.setText(sql);
       jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
       JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
       JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,con);
       JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
     } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | JRException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
```

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: no pages means your datasource is empty..

Comment: i found the solution.but there is a problem that ireport is only taking integer values.sorry but my datasource was not empty.thank for your support.

Comment: but please tell me whether ireport takes values only for integer values?